# Remove duplicate objects in an array based on id and date

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, ecmascript-6, filter

I want to remove duplicate object records based on **id** but should show the latest object record based on **pubDate**. Here is my sample array:

```
var arr = [
  {fileID: "1234", pubDate: "04/13/2018", id: "4979146", jobID: "9146", downloadURL: "", title: null},
  {fileID: "1235", pubDate: "04/13/2020", id: "4979147", jobID: "9147", downloadURL: "", title: null},
  {fileID: "1236", pubDate: "02/23/2021", id: "4979148", jobID: "9148", downloadURL: "", title: null},
  {fileID: "1237", pubDate: "01/15/2021", id: "4979148", jobID: "9148", downloadURL: "", title: null},
  {fileID: "1238", pubDate: "05/17/2019", id: "4979146", jobID: "9146", downloadURL: "", title: null}
];
```

Expected Output:

```
[
    {fileID: "1236", pubDate: "02/23/2021", id: "4979148", jobID: "9148", downloadURL: "", title: null}, 
    {fileID: "1235", pubDate: "04/13/2020", id: "4979147", jobID: "9147", downloadURL: "", title: null},
    {fileID: "1238", pubDate: "05/17/2019", id: "4979146", jobID: "9146", downloadURL: "", title: null}
];
```

Here's what I tried:

```
var result = arr.reduce((unique, o) => {
  if (!unique.some(obj => obj.id === o.id)) {
    unique.push(o);
  } 
  return unique;
}, []);
```

... but it seems to miss the logic to keep the latest record.

Comment: show what you have tried

Comment: var result = arr.reduce((unique, o) => {
    if(!unique.some(obj => obj.id === o.id )) {
      unique.push(o);
    }
    return unique;
},[]);


Missing the logic to keep the latest record :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this solution works for you?

```js
var arr = [
  {fileID: "1234", pubDate: "04/13/2018", id: "4979146", jobID: "9146", downloadURL: "", title: null},
  {fileID: "1235", pubDate: "04/13/2020", id: "4979147", jobID: "9147", downloadURL: "", title: null},
  {fileID: "1236", pubDate: "02/23/2021", id: "4979148", jobID: "9148", downloadURL: "", title: null},
  {fileID: "1237", pubDate: "01/15/2021", id: "4979148", jobID: "9148", downloadURL: "", title: null},
  {fileID: "1238", pubDate: "05/17/2019", id: "4979146", jobID: "9146", downloadURL: "", title: null}
];


function getUniqItems(arr) {
    const uniqueHash = arr.reduce((acc,o)=>{
        if (!acc[o.id]) {
            acc[o.id] = [];
        }
        acc[o.id].push(o);
        return acc;
    }
    , {});
    return Object.values(uniqueHash).reduce((acc,list)=>{
        list.sort((a,b)=>new Date(b.pubDate) - new Date(a.pubDate));
        acc.push(list[0]);
        return acc;
    }
    , []);
}

console.log(getUniqItems(arr));
```

Comment: No need to go through the list twice (and store all the values, then sort them); using new Date directly might blow in your face if there are inconsistencies in data.

Comment: I just did the grouping first then figured out what elements needs to picked from it. Agreed, iterating twice is not necessary for this requirement but in general it's useful too. And I believe just throwing an error conditionally will not keep quite too, it'll blow as well.
Anyways it's developer's choice to make that judgement what better fits for his needs, :)

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track, but you need to add the comparison when looking for result to override. For example:

```js
var arr = [
  {fileID: "1234", pubDate: "04/13/2018", id: "4979146", jobID: "9146", downloadURL: "", title: null},
  {fileID: "1235", pubDate: "04/13/2020", id: "4979147", jobID: "9147", downloadURL: "", title: null},
  {fileID: "1236", pubDate: "02/23/2021", id: "4979148", jobID: "9148", downloadURL: "", title: null},
  {fileID: "1237", pubDate: "01/15/2021", id: "4979148", jobID: "9148", downloadURL: "", title: null},
  {fileID: "1238", pubDate: "05/17/2019", id: "4979146", jobID: "9146", downloadURL: "", title: null}
];

function parse(pubDateStr = '') {
  const parts = pubDateStr.match(/\d+/g);
  if (!parts || parts.length !== 3) throw new Error(`Unexpected date format: [ ${pubDateStr} ]`); 
  return `${parts[2]}-${parts[0]}-${parts[1]}`;
}

const results = Object.values(arr.reduce((hash, curr) => {
  const prev = hash[curr.jobID];
  if (!prev || parse(prev.pubDate) < parse(curr.pubDate)) {
    hash[curr.jobID] = curr;
  }
  return hash;
}, {}));

// added sorting here as it seems to be sorted in your example, 
// albeit not mentioned in OP
console.log(results.sort((a, b) => b.jobID - a.jobID));
```

You don't need to go through list twice (as in the alternative solution), and you definitely don't need to store all the records, then sort them; it's enough to do the comparison when checking whether or not a record should be added.

As for using a specific function to parse MM/DD/YYYY instead of `new Date`: first, you guard against "browser differences and inconsistencies" [mentioned at MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date), second, it should handle missing and incorrect dates better (new Date(null) just gives you 1970-01-01, for example).